# How can I access the usb of my device from inside a Lil'Debi chroot?

Tags: root-access, usb, linux, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I am attempting to run adb from a Lil'Debi chroot enviroment. Unfortunately, I keep getting no devices in attached device list. The enviroment created by Lil'Debi links some system folders but does not    link /dev; I expect because Android /dev and Linux /dev are not fully compatible. I'm not even sure if this is a requirement for accessing the usb but I have read that since Lil'Debi chroot runs with full root priveleges that I am supposed to be able to access all the devices.

Comment: I have recursively bind mounted /dev/bus to /debian/dev/bus and can now get a read out from lsusb but adb still reports no device attached.

Comment: `adbd` uses Android/Linux kernel's USB gadget/device mode to expose itself to a USB host like a PC connected at the other end of USB. You are trying to access USB device from within USB device, not a host. It won't work simply. Better use ADB over network.

Comment: @Irfan Latif - Honestly, the goal is not to be able to adb from Lil'Debi chroot, that was just to try to test the connectivity of the usb device. The ultimate goal is to be able to use Rockchip usb tools from one android device to another. Unfortunately, the Rockchip usb tools are proprietary and only compiled to run in a Linux or Windows enviroment thus the need of the Linux enviroment created by Lil'Debi. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: https://github.com/guardianproject/lildebi/issues/41

Comment: @Aayush - after reading that I modified Lil'Debis' start up scripts to include 'mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs $mnt/dev' and now have the following when issuing mount command with no args - devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=458172k,nr_inodes=114543,mode=755)

Comment: @Aayush - however still have same problem, I can connect a device and it will be identified when issuing lsusb command but adb still sees no device. I have noticed, both when using the bind mount as well as after having made the devtmpfs mount, that when issuing lsusb command it first says - libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Function not implemented - before reporting the usb devices on the bus.